# sprintf in codeigniter not showing up

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to use `%s` in my language file for user name but is not working Just leaves a blank area on the page. I am pretty sure I have the `sprintf` correct for codeigniter.

`sprintf($this->lang->line('text_logged'), $this->users->getUserName());`

Any ideas on how to make `%s` work

It Should look like this `You are login as admin.`

But currently looks like `You are login as .`

**Header Controller**

```
public function index() {
  $baseUrl = base_url();
  $arrayExplore = explode('/',$baseUrl);
  $myLastElement = end($arrayExplore);

  $homeUrl = str_replace("admin/","",$baseUrl);

  $data = array(
    'home_url' => $homeUrl,
  );

  $data['text_logged'] = sprintf($this->lang->line('text_logged'), $this->users->getUserName());

  $this->load->view('template/common/header', $data);
}
```

**Language File it is loaded in the construct area. The code below is what is on language file**

`$lang['text_logged']   = 'You are logged in as %s.';`

**My user lib function to get user name**

```
public function getUserName() {
  return $this->CI->input->post('username');
}
```

Comment: I don't think you keep the username POSTing from page to page. Don't you keep it in session?

Comment: it is added in sessions I can see it

Comment: If your username is in the session, you should get it straight from there, instead of using post(); Like; return $this->session->userdata('username'); in your GetUserName() function.

Comment: I tried in my lib function `$getUserName = $this->CI->session->userdata('username');
if ($getUserName) {
return $getUserName['username'];
} else {
return false;
}` returns illegal string offset 'username'

Comment: That's because $getUserName isn't an array. Just return $getUsername, and not $getUsername['username']

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think this is how your getUsername() method should look like:

```
public function getUserName() {
  return $this->CI->session->userdata('username');
}
```

Make sure session lib is always loaded.

Comment: Are you using CI's sessions, or PHP's native sessions?

Comment: Normal codeigniter sessions your way worked now. I can see admin name